# Unbound no servers could be reached

Tags: debian, dns

I'm about to install a mail server and would like to use local DNS resolution but I tried to install Unbound manually and using [Angristan's Unbound installer](https://github.com/Angristan/Local-DNS-resolver). All I get when testing using `dig @127.0.0.1 google.ca` or `dig google.ca` is

> ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> @127.0.0.1 google.ca
>
> ; (1 server found)
>
> ;; global options: +cmd
>
> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

This is on a nearly untouched install of Debian 9 with LAMP and default firewall settings which is set to allow all traffic.

/etc/unbound/unbound.conf:

```
server:
root-hints: /var/lib/unbound/root.hints
auto-trust-anchor-file: /var/lib/unbound/root.key
interface: 127.0.0.1
access-control: 127.0.0.1 allow
port: 53
do-daemonize: yes
num-threads: 2
use-caps-for-id: yes
harden-glue: yes
hide-identity: yes
hide-version: yes
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
#nameserver 8.8.8.8
#nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
<myserverip>  mail.<mysite>.ca <myhostname>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

result of systemctl status -l -n100 unbound

```
● unbound.service - Unbound DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/unbound.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-10-22 12:36:30 PDT; 9s ago
     Docs: man:unbound(8)
  Process: 28745 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/unbound/package-helper root_trust_anchor_update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28740 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/unbound/package-helper chroot_setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28750 (unbound)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/unbound.service
           └─28750 /usr/sbin/unbound -d

Oct 22 12:35:40 joshtism systemd[1]: Stopping Unbound DNS server...
Oct 22 12:35:40 joshtism systemd[1]: Stopped Unbound DNS server.
Oct 22 12:35:40 joshtism systemd[1]: Starting Unbound DNS server...
Oct 22 12:36:30 joshtism package-helper[28745]: /var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
Oct 22 12:36:30 joshtism package-helper[28745]: fail: the anchor is NOT ok and could not be fixed
Oct 22 12:36:30 joshtism systemd[1]: Started Unbound DNS server.
Oct 22 12:36:30 joshtism unbound[28750]: [28750:0] notice: init module 0: validator
Oct 22 12:36:30 joshtism unbound[28750]: [28750:0] notice: init module 1: iterator
Oct 22 12:36:30 joshtism unbound[28750]: [28750:0] info: start of service (unbound 1.6.0).
```

lsof -p 28750

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
unbound 28750 unbound  cwd       DIR              202,1     4096 259993 /etc/unbound
unbound 28750 unbound  rtd       DIR              202,1     4096      2 /
unbound 28750 unbound  txt       REG              202,1  1080144  25646 /usr/sbin/unbound
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    47632    977 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    47688    979 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    89064    974 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    31616    975 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1  1063328    971 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    10688    988 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1   105088   2384 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1   170128  10380 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.2
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    14640    970 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1  2686672   9755 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1  4580776  17708 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1   293264   5742 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    38904  17688 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfstrm.so.0.0.0
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1    35064  17698 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1   442920   9756 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1  1689360    966 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1   135440    984 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound  mem       REG              202,1   153288    959 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
unbound 28750 unbound    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0   6431 /dev/null
unbound 28750 unbound    1u     unix 0xffff88b979d80800      0t0 237737 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound    2u     unix 0xffff88b979d80800      0t0 237737 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound    3u     IPv4             237762      0t0    UDP localhost:domain
unbound 28750 unbound    4u     IPv4             237763      0t0    TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)
unbound 28750 unbound    5u     IPv6             237764      0t0    TCP localhost:8953 (LISTEN)
unbound 28750 unbound    6u     IPv4             237765      0t0    TCP localhost:8953 (LISTEN)
unbound 28750 unbound    7u     unix 0xffff88b97c2bc000      0t0 237766 type=DGRAM
unbound 28750 unbound    8u     unix 0xffff88b9765d3800      0t0 237776 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound    9u     unix 0xffff88b97ac7ec00      0t0 237777 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound   10u     unix 0xffff88b97b107400      0t0 237778 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound   11u     unix 0xffff88b976515800      0t0 237779 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound   12u  a_inode               0,11        0   6425 [eventpoll]
unbound 28750 unbound   13u     unix 0xffff88b9765d3000      0t0 237780 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound   14u     unix 0xffff88b97cbb7c00      0t0 237781 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound   15u  a_inode               0,11        0   6425 [eventpoll]
unbound 28750 unbound   16u     unix 0xffff88b97c2bcc00      0t0 237782 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound   17u     unix 0xffff88b97c2bc800      0t0 237783 type=STREAM
unbound 28750 unbound   19u     IPv4             246217      0t0    UDP *:33533
```

unbound-anchor -a /var/lib/unbound/root.key -v:

```
/var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
```

Comment: Please show the output of `systemctl status -l -n100 unbound` for a start.

Comment: @FerencWágner updated with result

Comment: The start of the output seems missing, please fill it in. Let's see the output of `lsof -p 20423` as well.

Comment: @FerencWágner added full output of unbound status and lsof -p 28750. 20423 and 28745 was empty

Comment: OK. What's the result of `sudo unbound-anchor -a /var/lib/unbound/root.key -v` (see [Debian bug #667740](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=667740))? Also check your unbound logs; since the daemon is listening, it may have something to say about the incoming queries. Maybe increase logging verbosity beforehand.

Comment: Added result "... has content". I'm a little tied up right now but I'll update later tonight using the tips in that bug report.

Comment: @FerencWágner Alright so I increased verbosity all the way up to 5 to give me the most info and when I start unbound it doesn't give me any more info as to why it's not ok, and neither does running the mentioned unbound-anchor command. There are no fails or errors in the log either. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @JoshQuake I have exactly the same problem... Ever found a solution?

Comment: @b4d Negative. I've done hours upon hours of searching and couldn't find an answer. I debated just switching to Ubuntu but with my luck I would still have issues.

Comment: @JoshQuake I found my mistake... Forgot to allow all local connections in iptables :/ Adding this solved my problem:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT`

[source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @b4d

Solved by allowing all local connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```